Github CLI: repo counts without details
The --limit option of gh has an upper value limit. This is set to reasonable values, and for understandable reasons; as discussed here.
It can be convenient to format the output of gh as JSON, and filter using jq. For example the command below returns the number of repositories created in 2023 using the Raku language (which is 412). It takes about 18 seconds for this on my machine:
gh search repos -L 1000 language:Raku --created 2023 --json name --jq length
But if I omit the JSON/jq parts, and remove the -L 1000, the command returns more quickly (3 seconds), and the 412 value I am interested in, is still visible:
gh search repos language:Raku --created 2023

Showing 30 of 412 repositories

NAME                      DESCRIPTION            VISIBILITY  UPDATED            
vushu/raylib-raku         Raylib bindings fo...  public      about 2 months ago
...

Beyond merely running more quickly, this can be essential for a query returning a value above the upper limit. For example, with gh search repos language:Fortran --created 2023 I can see the value is 4067, but using the JSON/js approach alongside the maximum -L 1000 will return only the value: 1000.
How can I extract the number of repositories? I might consider grep /awk etc, but piping the output seems to remove the header containing the number of repositories? Or perhaps there is a simple option in gh?

Likely, the gh command goes to some interface of github to obtain the information, and the result likely starts with the header that you see. When you tell gh to do more, it will take longer, and when you want to see the names, it might have to fetch additional information for each match, all of this taking time... I can reproduce that the relevant line vanishes when the the output is not terminal and seems not to be available, a pity... I suggest to open an issue on github.com/cli/cli

Thanks. The data that is normally processed via JSON/jq indeed seems distinct from this "header" part. I could see such an issue as a useful feature request rather than a bug report. For now, I will hope that someone with knowledge of the standard IO connections can think of some script commands to help me out.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/how-to-trick-a-command-into-thinking-its-output-is-going-to-a-terminal
